# cron expression to run script on the last working day of the month

Tags: cron

I need to schedule a cron job to run on the last "working day" of the month. Please can someone advise me on how to achieve that?

thanks
Nick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron job to run on the last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139189/cron-job-to-run-on-the-last-day-of-the-month)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330563/compare-a-given-date-is-last-business-day-of-a-month-using-shellscript  - Ive tried to use the script here but it does not work by ignoring the weekends as the last business day of the month

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this with crontab alone. You will have to run your application every day and have it decide if today is the last working day of a month or not and take appropriate action.